# How to delete versions of an object in S3 bucket via lifecycle rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have set up an S3 bucket consisting of 2 main paths:

- private/
- public/

For the private/ folder I would like the following rule to be set up:

- Versions of all files in private/ are sent to S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval* and are kept for a minimum of 10 years.

And for the public/ folder the following rule:

- Versions of all files in public/ are sent to S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval* and are kept for a minimum of 6 months.

I currently have created the lifecycle rule for the public/ folder on a testing S3 bucket, and I have tried setting the expiration date to 1 day, to see if it works. However it does not.
This is the lifecycle rule which I created:
[image: public lifecycle rule on test bucket]

So basically I have selected:

- "Move noncurrent versions of objects between storage classes" checked
  and in this one I choose the option Glacier Instant Retrieval with 0 days after objects become noncurrent. And left the "Number of newer versions to retain" field empty.

For this point when I browse to my S3 bucket and I click on a version that has the delete marker set on them, it shows me "**Storage class: Standard**". Why is this not in the Glacier Instant Retrieval storage?

- "Permanently delete noncurrent versions of objects" checked
  and I selected 1 in the "Days after objects become noncurrent".

For the object I am looking at the versions, they are all 2 days old but they are still all in there. Why aren't they deleted?

Comment: "a version that has the delete marker set on them" - what do you mean by that? You want to move to the glacier deleted objects or their delete markers?

Comment: Sorry! I mean the objects that have the delete marker set, so I think it means all the noncurrent versions of the object.

Comment: I think AWS does not guarantee when the transfer happens. It is usually within 1 day, but can be longer.

Comment: So my lifecycle rule(s) are correct and they should do what I expect them to do, but I should wait a bit more before I can see something happening? Because now my files are from 08/02 , and still showing up.

Comment: I'm not sure if they are correct, but a delay is possible as well.